# Android: Edittext force format

Tags: android, android-edittext, format

how do I force a specific format in an Edittext.
Example:

the Userinput is: 123456789AB
the format should be: 123.4567.89AB
the best is, the conversion of the format is on-the-fly.
second solution is, an conversion of the string in backround without showing in the Edittext.

ps: the Edittext is created dynamically in AlertBuilder

Comment: You will probably want to work with the `DecimalFormat` class as you need it programmatically and then display the text in your `EditText` after you have formatted it as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

**add an listener(textWatcher) to your EditText**

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // you can call or do what you want with your EditText here
            yourEditText. ... 

          }

          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
       });
```

you can stop it for entering it. And you can also add Filters to it.

**If you want to filter input characters in your EditText, you need to use InputFilter. Here is example.
//Allow only letters or digits**

```
 InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
   public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
     Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
              if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) { 
                  return ""; 
              }
          }
    return null;
   } 
        }; 

 EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
text.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you

```
 yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    if(count%3==0)
                        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditText).setText(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditText).getText().toString()+"."));
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
             });
```

Similary you can go on as per your requirements